# Parameterize the Curl Request via shell script

Tags: linux, shell, curl, sh

I want a shell script where i can parameterize curl http request

Example:  curl -v "http://google.com/text={var)

{var) = hi, hello , how are you etc..

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can use variables.

See this example :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
var=$1
echo "I'm calling a command with '$var' argument"
```

output when calling `./test.sh hello`

```
I'm calling a command with 'hello' argument
```